# How to check if a geoserver layer is raster or vector using gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver, gsconfig

I am using gsconfig and python in order to retrieve information regarding some geoserver layers.

What I am trying to do is to find out if a specific layer is raster or vector.
I read online that I need to use get_resource function to do that.

This is what I do:

```
name = "layer_name"
workspace = "my_workspace"
cat = Catalog(location, user,pass)
resource = cat.get_resource(name, workspace=workspace)
```

The question is how to get the type of the layer after that. When I print the resource I get:

```
 <geoserver.resource.Coverage object at 0x7fb2f8ffca90>
```

And if the layer is vector then I get:

```
 <geoserver.resource.FeatureType object at 0x7fb2f9e64c50>
```

What's the way to access the properties of the layer and see if its vector or raster so later I can do something like this:

```
if layer = "raster":
   # do something
elif layer = "vector":
  # do something else
```

---

Doing:

```
 print dir(resource)
```

I get back a list with the attributes of the class:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_href', '_store', '_workspace', 'abstract', 'advertised', 'catalog', 'clear', 'dirty', 'dom', 'enabled', 'fetch', 'href', 'keywords', 'latlon_bbox', 'message', 'metadata', 'metadata_links', 'name', 'native_bbox', 'projection', 'projection_policy', 'refresh', 'request_srs_list', 'resource_type', 'response_srs_list', 'save_method', 'serialize', 'store', 'supported_formats', 'title', 'url_part_stores', 'url_part_types', 'workspace', 'writers']
```

---

With help from @iant, I found a way to see if my layer is vector or raster. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but it works.

I actually followed step by step @iant's answer but in my if statements instead of putting:

```
if type(resource) is geoserver.resource.Coverage:
    # this wouldn't work properly.
```

I put this:

```
a = str(type(resource)) 
if a == "<class 'geoserver.resource.Coverage'>":
```

So I actually transformed the result of type(resource) into a string.
It should be the case that the first way does work. I am not sure why it fails.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object help?

Comment: Using dir(resource) I get back a list of the attributes of the class as I added on my edit. I am not sure if some of this attribute indicates the layer's type!

Comment: I was thinking of type(layer) is Coverage

Comment: I am not getting you. type(resource) will return geoserver.resource.Coverage or geoserver.resource.FeatureType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my reading of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object) you should be able to do:

```
name = "layer_name"
workspace = "my_workspace"
cat = Catalog(location, user,pass)
resource = cat.get_resource(name, workspace=workspace)

if type(resource) is geoserver.resource.Coverage:
   ...
elif type(resource) is geoserver.resource.FeatureType:
   ...
```

Or possibly:

```
if isinstance(resource, geoserver.resource.Coverage):
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try this but it returns an error. When I print the type(resource) I get: <class 'geoserver.resource.FeatureType'>. Should I try comparing type(resource) is class 'geoserver.resource.FeatureType' ?

Comment: I don't know if this is good practice but I decided to transform the type(resource) into a string and compare in your if statements the two strings as: a = str(type(resource))  if a == "<class 'geoserver.resource.Coverage'>": ...

Comment: Best practice is to use `isinstance`.

Comment: Yup. But none of these work. When I try to use the isinstance my atom pops up that geoserver is an unknown variable. I also tried to use quotes but this doesn't solve the problem.